# Scroll to element on page load with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a functional component that fetches data from an API and renders it to a list. After the data is fetched and rendered I want to check if the URL id and list item is equal, if they are then the list item should be scrolled into view.

Below is my code:

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export default function ListComponent(props) {
  const scrollTarget = useRef();

  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [scrollTargetItemId, setScrollTargetItemId] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      let response = await fetch("someurl").then((res) => res.json());

      setItems(response);
    };
    
    fetchData();

    if (props.targetId) {
      setScrollTargetItemId(props.targetId)
    }

    if (scrollTarget.current) {
      window.scrollTo(0, scrollTarget.current.offsetTop)
    }
  }, [props]);

  let itemsToRender = [];
  itemsToRender = reports.map((report) => {   

    return (
      <li
        key={report._id}
        ref={item._id === scrollTargetItemId ? scrollTarget : null}
      >
        {item.payload}
      </li>
    );
  });

  return (
    <Fragment>
          <ul>{itemsToRender}</ul>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

My problem here is that `scrollTarget.current` is always `undefined`. Please advice what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if you use `useLayoutEffect` instead of `useEffect`? It should wait for everything to be rendered before running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because when a reference is changed, it does not cause a re-render.

From React's docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

> Keep in mind that `useRef` doesn’t notify you when its content changes. Mutating the `.current` property doesn’t cause a re-render. If you want to run some code when React attaches or detaches a ref to a DOM node, you may want to use a `callback ref` instead.

Answer (score 6):

Using useCallback, as @yagiro suggested, did the trick!

My code ended up like this:

```
const scroll = useCallback(node => {
    if (node !== null) {
      window.scrollTo({
        top: node.getBoundingClientRect().top,
        behavior: "smooth"
      })
    }
  }, []);
```

And then I just conditionally set the `ref={scroll}` on the node that you want to scroll to.

Comment: Could also do `node.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start'});`

Answer (score 0):

```
      constructor(props) {
            thi.modal = React.createRef();
          
        }
    
    handleSwitch() {
            // debugger
            this.setState({ errors: [] }, function () {
                this.modal.current.openModal('signup') // it will call function of child component of Modal
            });
            // debugger
        }
    
    
    return(
    <>
 
    <button className="login-button" onClick={this.handleSwitch}>Log in with email</button>

  
    <Modal ref={this.modal} />

</>

    )
```

Answer (score 0):

React Hooks will delay the scrolling until the page is ready:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const element = document.getElementById('id')
    if (element)
        element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })
}, [])
```

If the element is dynamic and based on a variable, add them to the Effect hook:

```
const [variable, setVariable] = useState()
const id = 'id'

useEffect(() => {
    const element = document.getElementById(id)
    if (element)
        element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })
}, [variable])
```